Questions about Cantor's first uncountability proof and the definition of R
I have a question about Cantor's first uncountability proof.
What definition of $\mathbb{R}$ did Cantor use in his proof? Is that, for example, build on the axiom about bounded sets or build on the axiom formulated using interval nests?
I tried to find it in the original proof, but I can't find it. Who can help me with a good source?
Maybe anyone can help me, thanks in advance!

See Bibliography: Cantor (1874)

Cantor's def of reals (1872)

Google phrase search for the title of Cantor's first (1874) paper: Ueber eine eigenschaft des inbegriffes aller reellen algebraischen zahlen. For various published translations of Cantor's papers, see the answers to Does There Exist a LaTeX/Word Rewrite of Georg Cantor's Works?.
